# how can i use 2 form fields with same name but use only the filled out one to insert data into mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

i have this html:

```
<p>
<strong>category:</strong> 
<input type="text" name="categorytext"> 
<select name="categoryselect">
  <option value="">-select-</option>
  <option value="Paper">Paper</option>
  <option value="Envelopes">Envelopes</option>
  <option value="Mail Supplies">Mail Supplies</option>
  <option value="Software">Software</option>
  <option value="Labels">Labels</option>
  <option value="Misc">Misc</option>
</select>
```

i then want to grab the value of the field that has been filled in and put it in a insert or update query.  so if text field is filled out, then that value will go into the 'category' field of table.  if a selection was made in the dropdown box, then that value will be inserted into the 'category' field of table.

so let's say this is my insert line:

```
INSERT INTO inventory_vendors (category) VALUES ('" . $_POST["category"] . "')
```

i want to put something before that line that let's php know which value to use.

something like:

```
if ($_POST["categorytext"] == "") {
    $category = $_POST["categoryselect"];
} else {
    $category = $_POST["categorytext"];
}
```

will something like that work?  is there a better way?

EDIT:

i guess i would need to change insert line if i wanted to use a variable.  would the following work:

```
INSERT INTO inventory_vendors (category) VALUES ('" . $category . "')
```

EDIT #2:

what can i do if someone tries to type text and select an option at the same time?

EDIT #3:

how is escaping done?  where in code do i update it to include escaping?

Comment: Instead of checking if it's an empty string, you could use `empty()`. `if(!empty($_POST['categorytext'])) { ... }`. And **your INSERT query is vulnerable to SQL injection**. You need to properly escape the user input before inserting them to a database.

Comment: ^--« I was going to suggest the same thing.

Comment: Your question title doesn't match the body though. In the title, you ask "*how can i use 2 form fields with same name*", but in the code you've provided, the `name` attributes are different. I don't know what exactly you're confused about.

Comment: sorry about that. originally i was going to use same field name in both but then realized that they needed to be different, so php can have something different in the "if" and in the "else".

Comment: As per edit #3, if you're using `mysqli_*` functions, which we don't know which API you're using or DB connection variable, do `$category = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$_POST["categoryselect"]);` @leoarce or use prepared statements/PDO.

Comment: thanks everyone.  a combination of all suggestions helped me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The piece of code you provided should work, but beware of security issues.

You can also use JavaScript to check for fields values and fill in an hidden "category" field, that will be POSTed with the form.

Generaly, you shouldn't directly use POSTed data in textual queries like you do. One can fill in your forms with SQL code and make what is called SQL injection.

Example: If i fill in your form with a category named "'); truncate table inventory_vendors; select ('1" => I just drop your entire table. Always escape incoming data and restrict the rights of your SQL user. The best practice is to use an ORM or a framework to handle your queries.